# Mock a single function call in another class

Tags: mocking, phpunit

`classA::getValue()` calls a method in another class, `classB::verifyValue()`. Since `classB::verifyValue()` has external dependencies, I want to be able to mock it to simply return `true` inside my unit test.

I don't want to touch anything else in `classB`, just this one method.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a test stub as Spidy suggests or you can use PHPUnit's built-in [mock objects](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/3.5/en/test-doubles.html). Both require that you be able to provide the `classB` instance for `classA` to use.

```
function testGetValue() {
    // set up mock classB
    $b = $this->getMock('classB', array('verifyValue'));
    $b->expects($this->once())
      ->method('verifyValue')
      ->will($this->returnValue(true));

    // set up classA
    $a = ...
    $a->setClassB($b);

    // test getValue()
    ... $a->getValue() ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use interfaces and a MockClassB in your test. For example, interfaceB has verifyValue(). So classB implements interfaceB and overrides verifyValue. Then you create another class called MockClassB and have it also implement interfaceB. In your test code, rather then creating classB, create MockClassB (MockClassB will return true rather then relying on external dependencies).

If that doesn't make enough sense, look up "programming to an interface, not an implementation"